# How to add custom plugin controls to CkEditor

Tags: ajax, wysiwyg

I have made custom plugin for ckeditor in drupal ckeditor module.
The page where I am displaying CKEDITOR is loaded through AJAX and I am doing a replace div to show the CKEDITOR. 
the code for replaceDiv is:

```
function replaceDiv( div )
{
    if ( editor )
        editor.destroy();

    editor = CKEDITOR.replace( div ,
    {
        toolbar : 'Basic'/*'Basic'*/
    }); 
}
```

But, the problem is that in this way I am not getting my custom plugin displayed, I tried adding my control name in the toolbar definition in the array but it seems that I am not doing in the right way since it is not working!

Answer (score 1):

In `ckeditor.config.js` you need something like this:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function(config) {
  config.extraPlugins = 'vicheck';
  CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal('vicheck', '/sites/all/plugins/ckeditor/vicheck/');
  config.toolbar_DrupalBasic = [ [ 'Bold', 'Italic', '-', 'vicheck' ] ];
}
```

where vicheck is a plugin.

This works for me using an old CKEditor module. I don't know if the latest versions have any change.

Comment: using this syntax do i need to modify the replaceDiv() code?

Comment: b/c apparently its not working..

Comment: You have two separate question: add plugins into CKEditor, and use CKEditor on an Ajax page. Try do answer each first. My solution could solve the first problem, for the second I don't know, and I don't know the replaceDiv function. But it looks like you do not give the full config variable to your instanciation.

Comment: yeah thats the actual problem, that i have no idea about instantiation of the config variable, otherwise there is no problem in opening ckeditor through ajax, but my plugin wont show up